Multiple Submit button conditions not behaving as expected on Webform
I have set up the following conditions on the submit button on my Drupal 10 Webform:
State: Disabled if [ALL]

Number Field 1: empty
Number Field 2: empty
Text field: value is not "TEST"

State: Enabled if [ALL]

Text field: value is "TEST"


Displayed behavior:

The form is allowing me to submit if any of the number fields have a value, AND if the text field contains the "TEST" value. (good)

The form is allowing me to submit if NONE of the number fields have a value, AND if the text field contains the "TEST" value. (bad)


Expected / desired behavior:

If all of the number fields are empty, AND if the text field does NOT
contain the "TEST" value, then the submit button should be
deactivated.
If any of the number fields are filled, AND if the text
field does NOT contain the "TEST" value, then the submit button
should be deactivated.
If at least one of the number fields has a
value, AND the text field DOES contain the "TEST" value, then the
submit button should activate.


Basically, I only want someone to be able to submit the form if they have provided at least one number value AND they have provided the exact "TEST" value in the text field. Is there a "recipe" that will make this work?
